# Trigger AHK script based on the position of the mouse

Tags: autohotkey

Is it possible to trigger an AHK script based on the position of the mouse? Say, if I wanted to press a button or series of buttons on my keyboard if I move my mouse to the corner or edge of the screen. Also, can this be done multiple times per second until the mouse is moved out of the specified area?

All I could find from googling is AHK scripts for moving the mouse using the keyboard, when I want to do the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Easiest way I can think of to do what you are asking is to use [SetTimer](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) and [MouseGetPos](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/MouseGetPos.htm) to evaluate the position and if it matches than trigger your script.

The 2nd example code on the MouseGetPos is using SetTimer. This should get you headed in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

I did it, thanks Aaron and ahkcoder.

I got a little better feel with `Up` and `Down` instead of `PgUp` and `PgDn`, to anyone else, play with the timings until it's sufficient. You'll also need to modify the values for the edges of your screen.

```
; move up and down when mouse is at edges of screen
#Persistent
SetTimer, foo, 65
return

foo:
MouseGetPos, x, y, id, control
; ToolTip, %x% %y%
; will trigger only at edges of a full screen
if (y = 1087){
; bottom
send {Down}
send {Down}
send {Down}
; sleep, 300
}
else if(y = 8){
; top
send {Up}
send {Up}
send {Up}
}

return
```